# Sparse Matrix Interpolation With MATLAB

Tags: matlab, interpolation

If I have a matrix like this

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
```

I can use interp2 to interpolate it like this

```
newA = interp2(A,2);
```

and I get a 5x5 interpolated matrix.

But what if I have a matrix like this:

```
B = zeros(20);
B(3,2) = 5;
B(17,4) = 3;
B(16, 19) = 2.3;
B(5, 18) = 4.5;
```

How would I interpolate (or fill-in the blanks) this matrix.  I've looked into interp2 as well as TriScatteredInterp but neither of these seem to fit my needs exactly.

Comment: Why doesn't `TriScatteredInterp` fit your needs? It seems ideal.

Comment: Because Triscatteredinterp has problems extrapolating into the corners of the array. Based on a tessellation, it will interpolate only within the convex hull of the data.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A good solution is to use my [inpaint_nans](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551). Simply supply NaN elements where no information exists, then use inpaint_nans. It will interpolate for the NaN elements, filling them in to be smoothly consistent with the data points.

```
B = nan(20);
B(3,2) = 5;
B(17,4) = 3;
B(16, 19) = 2.3;
B(5, 18) = 4.5;
Bhat = inpaint_nans(B);

surf(B,'marker','o')
hold on
surf(Bhat)
```

[image: Inpainted surface from nearly empty array]

Edit:

For those interested in whether inpaint_nans can handle more complex surfaces, I once took a digitized Monet painting (seen on the left hand side, then corrupted it by deleting a random 50% of the pixels. Finally, I applied inpaint_nans to see if I could recover the image reasonably well. The right hand image is the inpainted one. While the resolution is low, the recovered image is a decent recovery.

[image: Garden at Sainte-Adresse]

As another example, try this:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(0:.01:2);
z = sin(3*(x+y.^2)).*cos(2*x - 5*y);
surf(x,y,z)
view(-23,40)
```

[image: base trig surface]

Now, delete about 7/8 of the elements of this array, replacing them with NaNs.

```
k = randperm(numel(z));
zcorrupted = z;
zcorrupted(k(1:35000)) = NaN;
```

Recover using inpainting. The z-axis has a different scaling because there are minor variations above and below +/-1 around the edges, but otherwise, the latter surface is a good approximation.

```
zhat = inpaint_nans(zcorrupted);
surf(x,y,zhat)
view(-23,40)
```

[image]

Comment: wow, nice piece of work indeed! Would you care to show a little bit more complicated example as well? Thanks

Comment: Also, thanks for using the BSD license.  If this was GPL or something like that I don't think I could use it.

Comment: Can I use your function in Octave?