# How to perform a checkerboard-interpolation in matlab?

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I have two matrices `A` and `B` containing values for a checkerboard/chessboard-like grid of the form

```
AxAxAxAx...
xBxBxBxB...
AxAxAxAx...
xBxBxBxB...
...........
...........
```

Where `x` represents values not yet known which I want to (linearly) interpolate. What's the easiest way to achieve this?

First thing is probably

```
C = zeros(size(A)+size(B));
C(1:2:end,1:2:end) = A;
C(2:2:end,2:2:end) = B;
```

to obtain aforementioned matrix. Now I *could* loop through all remaining points and take the average of all direct neighbours, for 1) `for` loops in matlab are slow and 2) there's certainly a way to use `interp2`, though that seems to require a `meshgrid`-like grid. So, can this be done easier/faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to [woodchips'](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85109/woodchips) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021646/sparse-matrix-interpolation-with-matlab/5022213#5022213) I found his [inpaint_nans](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4551), the solution is indeed simple:

```
C = nan(size(A)+size(B));
C(1:2:end, 1:2:end) = A;
C(2:2:end, 2:2:end) = B;
C = inpaint_nans(C);
```